# PHP - taking textinput text

Tags: php, post, textinput

I need to take what the user writes into a text input and pass it to another page. 
I'm filtering variables passed in POST but this only gives me the possibility to take VALUES of elements, not the text itself... 
This is an example:

```
$name = filter_input ( INPUT_POST, 'name' );
```

This brings to $name being valorized to the value of the element with id 'name'.
What if I want to take the text typed by the user in a textinput?!

EDIT: this is the dead simple textinput I'm using:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="name">
```

Comment: the text entered in by the user is the value property of the element. Are you able to show me the code used for the input field? )just add it to your post_

Comment: add `name="name"` to `input`

Comment: @splash58 nope. Doesn't work. Already tried :)

Comment: success code - `if (! isset($_POST['name'])) {
 echo '<form method="post"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="name"></form>';
}
else
 echo $name = filter_input ( INPUT_POST, 'name' );
`

Comment: @splash58 I need to take the text and store it into a variable...

Comment: I took you code, put into file, which code above, and $name get the text from input. I don't understand your problem. I only changed id to name

Comment: @splash58 the textinput is in a form that sends all the values out via a POST request. In a second php page I take every values, store them into variables, apply some logic and then send them to a third page. I'm not trying to access the value of the inputtext from within the same page...